# Is semi-supervised regression useful?

Tags: regression, semi-supervised-learning

I understand why semi-supervised classification,
but don't know why semi-supervised regression is.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning#/media/File:Example_of_unlabeled_data_in_semisupervised_learning.png

The above link shows the usefulness of semi-supervised classification.
But this advantage does not make sense in regression.

Can anybody explain why it is useful?